# MQL4 casting between structures error

Tags: mql4

> Hello guys I'm having a struggle with casting 2 structures
>   It returns an error "Cannot cast mydouble to mydouble2"
>   In the old version of mql it was working well ...
>   Here it is the code

```
struct mydouble
{
uchar b0;
uchar b1;
uchar b2;
uchar b3;
uchar b4;
uchar b5;
uchar b6;
uchar b7;
};
struct mydouble2
{
double d0;
};

mydouble b;mydouble2 set;
dsize=total;
for(int i=0;i<total;i++)
{
  uchar buffer[60];
  int read[1];
  ReadFile(hst_file, buffer, 60, read, 0);
  data[i].time=(buffer[7]<<56)|(buffer[6]<<48)|(buffer[5]<<40)|(buffer[4]<<32)|(buffer[3]<<24)|(buffer[2]<<16)|(buffer[1]<<8)|buffer[0];

  b.b0=buffer[32];
  b.b1=buffer[33];
  b.b2=buffer[34];
  b.b3=buffer[35];
  b.b4=buffer[36];
  b.b5=buffer[37];
  b.b6=buffer[38];
  b.b7=buffer[39];

  set=(mydouble2)b; // HERE IT RETURNS ERROR: Cannot cast mydouble to mydouble2
  data[i].close=set.d0;
  }
```

Comment: And why do you think it should cast a structure with 8 chars to a structure with one double? write a clear function that will receive 8 chars or this structure and returns a double

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment but it was working as is on the older version of mql

Comment: maybe yes, but there is no reason why it should work (correctly) - double and char are different types